# Flask Reverse of layout pattern to create page from multiple components/templates

Tags: python, templates, flask, view, modular

I'm building a Website with Flask and it contains multiple views/tabs that are modular and should be replaceable depending on the client's request.

To that end, I'm trying to write a template index.html that includes multiple view templates (view1.html, view2.html, etc.)

It should thus be the reverse of the layout pattern where a base layout is created and multiple pages are derived from it. On the contrary, I search for a pattern where a single page is constructed from multiple components/templates that include HTML code.

I struggle to find a solution, and I don't know how to search for it either.

I was looking for something structured like:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', views=[
        render_template('view1.html'),
        render_template('view2.html'),
        render_template('view3.html'),
        render_template('view4.html')
    ])
```

if found a solution to include the views statically with `{% include 'view1.html' %}` in the index.html. If I can make this dynamic, making it possible to select the include files within render_template it would be a solution

Answer (score 0):

Solution using include and for loop in template:

in python code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', views=["view1", "view2", "view3"])
```

in index.html:

```
{% for v in views %}
    {% set path = '' + v + '.html' %}{% include path %}
{% endfor %}
```